# Record a window on macOS

Tags: macos, screen-recording

I know how to record a screen on macOS, including the <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>5</kbd> technique and using a third party application.

Is there a way of recording a *window*? I want to write some tutorial material with video.

I have a way to cheat: attach an old iPad with Duet, fill the additional screen with the window, and record the whole screen. But there must be a more practical way to do that.

I’m using macOS 11 Big Sur, if that makes a difference.

Comment: If the _window_ is going to stay in the same place on the screen and the same size, then use **⇧⌘5** and select **Record Selected Portion**, then adjust the _mask_ around that _window_, then click **Record**.

Comment: I have discovered https://window-recorder.rhardih.io/. This may do the job.